# Two dimensional grid graph implementation

Tags: c, algorithm, grid, 2d, graph-algorithm

I want to implement two dimensional grid graph in C. Is it better to start with a single node and continue adding nodes when it is required or forming it one at a time? Code snippet would be great.

Comment: Why dont you use a two dimensional array? http://www.eng.iastate.edu/efmd/cmultarray.html

Comment: What data are you storing per node?

Comment: I agree, a code snippet from you telling us what you are thinking would be great.

Comment: here i will have to store some data in the node as a record. i am implimenting to spread random walker over the network.  i will do polling to fined out the neighbour who has least dense of walker at a particular time step.

Answer (score 0):

First of all StackOverflow community doesn't like to give whole solutions to given problems. It's always better to propose something on your own and show that you thought the problem over. Your problem statement is not specific. Do you know the number of vertices at compile time? If so the simple two-dimensional array would be enough:

```
int connections[100][100];
```

If not but the number of vertices is constant maybe you should consider using dynamic allocation:

```
int** connections = malloc(sizeof(int*)*numberOfVertices);
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfVertices; i++) {
    connections[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*numberOfVertices);
}
```

This two solutions of course cause some problems. They for example are very memory expensive (especially when the graph is sparse). This is why you always can use some dedicated struct.

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking of adding nodes as you go, then you should use an adjacency list (a linked list of linked lists) to represent your graph; especially since adding as you go means you don't know whether your graph will be parse. But if you already know the size of your graph, then use a square array (n by n, where n is number of nodes).

Comment: here i know every node will have four neighbors only as it is 2d grid graph. i also require every node should have unique identity as i have to spread random walker over the network. i will do polling to fined out which neighbour has least number of walker for forwarding the walker. so at each node there will be an array of size 4 to keep the these values.so, please suggest now. and also if you can provide any code snippet it will be great help to me.